# What method am I missing? MissingMethodException on project.apply plugin: 'customPlugin'

Tags: groovy, gradle, gradle-custom-plugin

What method am I missing?
I am getting a MissingMethodException on

```
project.apply plugin: 'env'
```

Here is my code:

--EnvPluginTest.groovy

```
package com.gradle.env;

import static org.junit.Assert.*
import org.junit.Test
import org.gradle.api.*
import org.gradle.testfixtures.*

class EnvPluginTest {

    @Test
    public void EnvPluginAddsEnvPluginExtensionToProject() {
        Project project =  ProjectBuilder.builder().build()
        project.apply plugin: 'env'

        assertTrue(project.extensions.getByName('env')  
            instanceof  EnvPluginExtension)
    }
}
```

--env.properties

```
implementation-class=com.gradle.env.EnvPlugin
```

--EnvPlugin.groovy

```
package com.gradle.env

import org.gradle.api.*;

class EnvPlugin implements Plugin<Project> {
    void apply(Project project) {
        project.configure {
            extensions.create("env",  
                EnvPluginExtension) 
        }
    }
}

class EnvPluginExtension {
    def env = EnvSingleton.instance
}

class EnvSingleton {

    String tcserverHome
    String javaHome

    private static final INSTANCE = new EnvSingleton()

    private EnvSingleton() {}

    static getInstance() {
        return INSTANCE
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The full stack trace should tell you where the problem is. You can get it from Gradle's HTML test report, from your IDE, or by reconfiguring `test.testLogging`.

PS: Please don't double-post here and on http://forums.gradle.org.

Comment: Ok let me check. 
Off-Topic: Sorry about double posting, the Gradle Forum through Get Satisfaction confuses me.

Comment: The stack trace has this:
 Could not find method configure() for arguments [com.gradle.env.EnvPlugin$_apply_closure1@e60d39] on root project 'test'.

I will try to add the configure() method to this test root project.

Comment: It's `project.configure(project) { ... }`.